# Short story about rock throwing fight

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story back in the 2001/2002 time frame while I was in middle school. It may have been assigned reading, or part of a text book, or a library book I can't remember. I was reading it during class at the time (7th or 8th grade USA). I believe it was a literature class. I only remember one specific scene, which may actually be the entirety of the story.

The scene I remember is school bullies pick on a certain kid and begin throwing either snowballs with rocks in them, or just rocks at him. I feel like this was a common occurance in the story setting. There may have been snow piles and banks because the main character takes cover. He ends up winning the fight (I think) because he has practiced throwing rocks so that they curve. He is accurate enough to curve the rocks around the cover the bullies are using and beats them even though there are many bullies.

What is the title of this short story and where can it be found?

Comment: Are there any science fictional or fantastical elements in this story that you can remember? As it stands I don't think this is on topic for the site as per the [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Check out this post on [How to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if you could think of any more details to add to your question to try make it on topic

Comment: I remember it feeling somewhat dystopian almost in a "The Giver" kind of way.

Comment: Do the rocks curve in a more or less unrealistic way, such as the bullets in *Wanted*? These ones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1d4BewyhlI. If so, I'd say it's on-topic. (not voting to close or leave open so far, though)

Comment: @Jenayah no they curve because they are somewhat flattened and thrown at an angle. Sounds like this may not be the correct SE. Moving to Literature.SE